# Align text in center using css

Tags: html, css, image, web

I used the following code for simple image gallery (actual code found in http://w3schools.com, it works perfectly). After editing css the alignment of text has been changed. I want to align the text at centre. Anybody knows the answer please help me.

My HTML Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="d">
<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm">
<img src="a.jpg">
</a>
<div class="desc">
Add a description of the image here </div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm">
<img src="a.jpg">
</a>
<div class="desc">
<p>
Add a description of the image here</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="klematis3_big.htm">
<img src="a.jpg">
</a>
<div class="desc">
Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="klematis4_big.htm">
<img src="a.jpg">
</a>
<div class="desc">
<p>
Add a description of the image here</P>
</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm">
<img src="a.jpg">
</a>
<div class="desc">
Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="klematis2_big.htm">
<img src="a.jpg">
</a>
<div class="desc">
Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS Code:

```
#d
{
width : 660;
border:1px;
}
.img
{
margin:3px;
border:1px solid #0000ff;
height:200;
width:200;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
.img img
{
display:inline;
margin:3px;
border:1px solid #ffffff;
width:100;
height : auto;
}
.img a:hover img
{
border:2px solid #0000ff;
}
.desc
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:normal;
width:120px;
margin:2px;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the width of the div.

```
.desc {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

And also change it to [text-align](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-align). The attribute align does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.desc{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to modify the value of the margin property:

```
.desc
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:normal;
width:120px;
margin:2px auto;
}
```

also the hash sign is missing in this part:

```
<style>

d
{
width : 660;
border:1px;
}
```

it has to be modified like this:

```
<style>

#d {
   width : 660;
   border:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change css to

```
.desc
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:normal;
width:120px;
margin:2px;
}
```

change `align:center;` to `text-align:center;`

Comment: pls check your css also, add 'px' values to height and width in .img eg .img{height:200px;width:200px;}

Answer (score 0):

.detail 
{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 auto;
}