# Simple: Text not centering in a HTML (moodle title label)

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to center the text on this moodle

```
<div>
    </div>
    <div style=";background-color: #585657;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top: auto;;height: 4rem; border-radius: 10px 20px 20px 20px;vertical-align:20%;border-right:20px solid rgba(233, 86, 34,0.8);border-top-right-radius: 80px 80px;border-bottom-left-radius: 80px 80px;border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 80px;border-top-left-radius: 80px 80px;border-left:20px solid rgba(233, 86, 34,0.8);">
        <div style="display: inline-block;display: inline-table; height:100%;overflow: hidden;">
            <span style="max-height: 3em;font-size:calc(80% + .25vw); !important;color:  !important;display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;font-family: Helvetica !important;font-weight:700;">ALALALLLLAAAAAA<br></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
```

I want some hrelp on how to solve my problem and maybe help making it look better

Comment: There are a very large number of other issues with this piece of code, but you can use `text-align: center` to horizontally center text within its container using CSS.  I do want to point out that you are encouraged to do some Googling prior to posting on StackOverflow, which would have found you questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786718/align-text-in-center-using-css) that will answer your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to center items/text in css, such as `text-align: center;`, however in the snippet below I have used `display: flex;`, then `align-items: center;` to vertically align the text, and `justify-content: center;` to horizontally align it.

```html
<div style="background-color: #585657; height: 4rem; border-left:20px solid rgba(233, 86, 34,0.8); border-right: 20px solid rgba(233, 86, 34,0.8); border-radius: 80px;">
    <span style="height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"><p style="font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: 700; font-size: calc(80% + .25vw);">ALALALLLLAAAAAA</p></span>
</div>
<br>
```

To help improve your code here are a few changes I've made:

1. Removed `!important` from CSS (this overrides all other style declarations for that element, making it harder to maintain)
2. Removed duplicate style declarations, such as `display: inline-block;display: inline-table;`, the second time you set the `display` property, it will override what you have written for the first one
3. Removed unnecessary `<div>` tags, and the `<br>` tag inside your `<span>`
4. Where possible changed CSS styles to use the shorthand versions, e.g. `border-top-right-radius: 80px 80px;border-bottom-left-radius: 80px 80px;border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 80px;border-top-left-radius: 80px 80px;` to simply `border-radius: 80px;`
5. Removed semi-colon from start of style declarations
6. Removed duplicate semi-colons from styles

To help learn the basics of HTML and CSS, W3 Schools have some really great tutorials: [CSS Tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) and [HTML Tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/html/).

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: Thank you for this comment @tchrist, I would just like to let you know though that as shocking as it is, I did indeed write this basic HTML and CSS  myself.